# Generate thumbnail of Microsoft Docs

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-office

Just wondered if it was possible to create a thumbnail / GIF image of a microsoft word document on the fly with C#?

I am working on a web application which is required to generate and display a thumbnail of various microsoft docs such as word, excel, ppt, etc..

They seem to be able to do it on Microsoft.com (see http://office.microsoft.com/template...3601033&CTT=98, for example) - Is there a function which does this?

Comment: I should be more specific.  I am aware there is a way of pulling the thumbnail using the Windows API and various other ways but the problem with all of these approaches is the document must be saved with the "save thumbnail" box checked.  If the thumb was not created when the doc was saved it simply pulls the icon.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  You can go through these links:

- http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=319350
- http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial219_Extracting-Icons-from-Files.html